# My team members' Visual studio team foundation server cannot find files I checked in

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, version-control

We're using team foundation server as source control management tool. I checked in my projects and files . But when my team members get the latest version of code, what happened is they can find the files in file explorer but not in the visual studio solution explorer. This results in they have to add the files manually by clicking on adding existing items.

Anyone knows any possible root cause for this?

Comment: You probably forgot to save your project file before you checked it in.

Comment: Are your proj files in TFS?  They should be.

Comment: yes. I forgot to pull out the .csproj file from excluded list. Thanks, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked in the files, but you also need to check in the updated solution (and/or) project files. Once they are checked in, have your teammates get the latest version of solution (and/or) project files.